# Why is my HTML text not changing colour using my CSS?

Tags: css

I can't seem to find the answer to this question.

I am trying to change the text color of the words "Pro Tip" in this code

```
<div style="background-color: #f7f7f7; padding: 1.0em; max-width: 45.0em; margin: 1.0em 0; border: solid 1.0px #cccccc;">
    <strong><text-color-#ff9800&g>tPRO TIP</>&lt;/&gt; -
    </strong> Text 2
</div>
```

NO matter what I Google nothing works.  How can I figure it out?  Also how can I write the code that fixes this?

https://www.screencast.com/t/U6KqJ9dIHVu

Comment: this is the code I am trying to modify (i deleted the div <> so I could post here... div style="background-color: #f7f7f7; padding: 1.0em; max-width: 45.0em; margin: 1.0em 0; border: solid 1.0px #cccccc;"><strong><text-color-#ff9800&g>tPRO TIP</>&lt;/&gt; -</strong> Text 2

Comment: Use `color` instead of `text-color`

Comment: It looks like you are expecting an HTML tag of `<text-color>`, but there is no such thing.

Comment: trying that still doesnt change the color https://www.screencast.com/t/DQTG9XtWUCL5

Comment: Halfer. Im not expecting anything I'm just trying things that I've discovered while googling "how to change text color"

Answer (score 1):

You can use the CSS property `color` to style the `<strong>` element.

```html
<div style="background-color: #f7f7f7; padding: 1.0em; max-width: 45.0em; margin: 1.0em 0; border: solid 1.0px #cccccc;">
  <strong style="color: #ff9800;">PRO TIP -
  </strong> Text 2
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The structure of what the code you have makes it hard to read and use. The attribute you need to target to change the colour of your text is 'color'. As you're using inline styles rather than a CSS stylesheet I'd use this instead:

```
    <div style="background-color: #f7f7f7; padding: 1.0em; max-width: 45.0em; margin: 1.0em 0; border: solid 1.0px #cccccc;">

        <div style="font-weight: bold; color: #ff9800">

            <p>PRO TIP</p>

        </div>

        <div>

            <p>Your text here</p>

        </div>

    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should remove &g from hex color. And there is no valid tag like text-color. That's why you should use style attribute in strong tag. font is not supported by HTML5. so better ignore it. Here this code works perfectly.

```
<div style="background-color: #f7f7f7; padding: 1.0em; max-width: 45.0em; margin: 
1.0em 0; border: solid 1.0px #cccccc;">
<strong style="color:#ff9800">tPRO TIP</>&lt;/&gt; -
</strong> Text 2</div>
```